# Bootstrap DateTimePicker hidden inside JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a bootstrap datetimepicker ([as here](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)) inside a JQuery dialog. However, when the datetimepicker is displayed, it is hidden inside of the dialog when i would like it to display on top of the dialog.

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see this is far from ideal.

I have researched and the only solution i seem to find is increasing the z-index to a large value but this doesnt seem to work. I have tried it with many different classes such as .datepicker .ui-datepicker .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget and also tried with and without !important but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody have any other ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="mui-textfield">
    <input type="date" id="txtDate"/>
    <label>Date</label>
</div>

$('#txtDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    keepOpen: false
});
```

Comment: can you provide the css relating to the datetimepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` did turn out to be the issue for me however, I also had to set `overflow: visible` on both the dialog and dialog content divs in order for it to be escaped. This is the css that worked for me in the end:

```
.datepicker
{
    z-index: 99999   !important;
}
.ui-dialog {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
.ui-dialog-content {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```